# How to integrate a WebJob within an Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'am trying to integrate a WebJob inside an ADF pipeline. 
The webjob is a very simple console application:

```
namespace WebJob4
{
    class ReturnTest
    {
        static double CalculateArea(int r)
        {
            double area = r * r * Math.PI;
            return area;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            int radius = 5;
            double result = CalculateArea(radius);
            Console.WriteLine("The area is {0:0.00}", result);       
        }
    }
}
```

How do we call this webjob through an ADF pipeline and store the response code (HTTP 200 in case of Success) in azure blob storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dec 2018 Update :

If you are thinking of doing this using azure function, azure data factory NOW provides you with an azure function step! the underlying principle is the same as you will have to expose the azure function with a HTTP trigger. however this provides better security since you can specify your data factory instance access to the azure function using ACL

> Reference : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/

---

### Orginal Answer

- From the comments posted I believe you dont want to use custom activities route.
- You could try using a copy task for this, even though probably this is not the intended purpose.
- there is a `httpConnector` available for copying data from a  web source.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-http-connector

- the copy task triggers an http endpoint,
- you can specify a variety of authentication mechanisms from Basic to
  OAuth2.
- below I am using the end point to trigger the azure function process, the output is saved in datalake folder for logging (you can use other things obviously, like in your case it would be blob storage.)

### Basic linked Service

```
{
  "name": "linkedservice-httpEndpoint",
  "properties": {
    "type": "Http",
    "typeProperties": {
      "url": "https://azurefunction.api.com/",
      "authenticationType": "Anonymous"
    }
  }
}
```

### Basic Input Dataset

```
{
  "name": "Http-Request",
  "properties": {
    "type": "Http",
    "linkedServiceName": "linkedservice-httpEndpoint",
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": 30
    },
    "typeProperties": {
      "relativeUrl": "/api/status",
      "requestMethod": "Get",
      "format": {
        "type": "TextFormat",
        "columnDelimiter": ","
      }
    },
    "structure": [
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "type": "String"
      }
    ],
    "published": false,
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
{
    "name": "Http-Response",
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            ...
        ],
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "linkedServiceName": "linkedservice-dataLake",
        "typeProperties": {
          ...
        },
        "availability": {
            ...
        },
        "external": false,
        "policy": {}
    }
}
```

#### Activity

```
{
        "type": "Copy",
        "name": "Trigger Azure Function or WebJob with Http Trigger",
        "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Day",
          "interval": 1
        },
        "typeProperties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "HttpSource",
            "recursive": false
          },
          "sink": {
            "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink",
            "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles",
            "writeBatchSize": 0,
            "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
          }
        },
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "Http-Request"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "Http-Response"
          }
        ],
        "policy": {
          ...
        }        
      }
```

Comment: Thanks @frictionlesspulley! It worked... Although in blob storage there is just a 0B file. I expected the response code to be stored. Can you explain why it did not store the response?

Comment: you can do this using the copy editor that is available on the portal as well, it gives a good idea about what part of the response you want to store. the sample ^ in the answer saves the response text. Probably there might be a better integration between azure function / webjob and data factory in the fututure, until then.. ACCEPT THE ANSWER ;)

Comment: One more question here for you @frictionlesspulley.. why is the gateway name needed in the linked service? Omitting it causes the pipeline to fail with in Error 409 : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.,Source=System,'. Gateway name is required for OnPremise sources and this Web Job  is OnCloud. Any idea?

Comment: the gateway is not required. i included those option just to display that you could use them if needed. 
UPDATED THE ANSWER :
check the basic example input which has worked for me in the past